# Restarting your Software deployment packages

Tags: deployment, software-distribution, sccm

Ok, so to keep my question simple I wanted to break down the situation.

I have groups listed in AD and are mirrored on SCCM.
In each group, I have select software deployed. 
Each group has say about 30 pc's

1 PC has stopped working due to a hard Drive failure. Easy Repair!
PC has been repaired (HDD replaced) and configured and placed back onto the same group in AD and SCCM.

Because I already deployed previously in this group, SCCM shows 100% completed.

I want to redeploy the same software for the group.

**Current method requires me to remove and setup the deployment package all over again.**

Does anyone know of a way to have it simply refresh the software deployments you have already done to scan and detect and reinstall as needed.

If you followed my example, you basically refresh the deployment.

It should scan and detect 29 pc's already have the software installed and one does not.  Thereby pushing the software out without me having to delete and create a new deployment package.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really follow. This is a package/program Installation right? Not an application type one? In this case normally, yes the reports will show 100% deployed, but the client on each of the new systems would detect a deployment for the specific machine, look up it's execution history and find it has not happened and still reinstall the software. The only cases where this would not happen is if you copied this part of the old registry to the new pc (which you probably did not) or if you have scheduled your deployment to expire after some time that has since passed

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have a select group of about a dozen or so programs that need to be installed. It honestly is annoying to have to redeploy the same packages. From what I understood, once deployment status reaches 100% it does not check. I did not put an end date for the installation. My team has tried to see if it will push out again on a test machine and it just did not.

Comment: Forgot to add, the repaired HDD/PC would be put back on the domain under the same PC name and not a different one. Hence it won't see a new PC but the same one.

Comment: Are we talking about normal programs here? or is this the point where I misunderstood you? The server does not have the last word in terms of deployment only the client has in this case. So if this is really the same record with the same deployments but locally the programs are missing it should always be reinstalled. it's the same if you image the client again with a new os. the programs would appear automatically, everything else would be pointless. or is the problem that the record has the same name but lost it's deployments?

Comment: Same Name lost its deployments.. Programs are normal nothing specialized, like MS office and other educational software.

Comment: Ok that can happen (although it probably should not either). But if you reassign the deployments, no recreation or anything just adding the record to the collections that are already available, the software will not be reinstalled after the next machine policy update of the client? If so could you check after a successful policy update where they should be installed what advertisements and execution history say in the client center (https://github.com/rzander/sccmclictr/releases)

Answer (score 0):

On the pc with the high drive crash I would delete that record from SCCM and reinstall the agent on that PC.  The SCCM DB probably will not updated right away, this may help the process.

Comment: Why would you do this? deleting the record does nothing if there is a local execution history (not even reinstalling the client does probably) and if there is none it would just reinstall anyway. Either just do a rerun via roger zanders client center if this is really more of a clone or just wait until everything fixes itself. you could claim deleting the record is useful because hw inventory might be wrong otherwise but is this really worth the effort for a hd failure when 90% of inventory will be the same and the rest is corrected in a week or so?

Comment: FYI- Once HDD is replaced part of the new image has the client installed already.

Comment: SCCM will removed stale PC records after 90 days by default,  you may want to search by mac address to make sure the PC does not have multiple records in SCCM.  This would cause some deployment issues.  This is why I suggested deleting and re-adding the PC to sccm.